# How to compute moving averages just for the new rows

Tags: r

I have a huge dataframe that is taking over 40 mins to compute simple moving averages (SMA) on several columns. The problem is that I cannot find a way to compute the SMAs for the new added rows alone.

The workaround I implemented was to manually compute each SMA, but I'm sure there's a way to use roll_mean or similar to do it.

Here's a script for you to reproduce what I have:

```
library(RcppRoll)

SMALen = c(18, 20, 22, 81, 90, 99, 135, 150, 165)
startDate <-  as.Date("1900-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2018-12-31")
numDays <- endDate - startDate + 1
myData <- data.frame(Date=seq(startDate, endDate, 1),
                     UVI=sample(1:10, numDays, rep=TRUE))

for (i in 1:length(SMALen)) {
    SMAValues <- roll_mean(myData$UVI,
                           SMALen[i],
                           na.rm=TRUE,
                           fill=NA,
                           align='right')
    myData <- cbind(myData, SMAValues)
    colName <- paste0("SMA", SMALen[i])
    names(myData)[ncol(myData)] = colName
}    

head(myData, 25)
tail(myData, 25)
```

Now I add a few more rows (7 more days in the code below):

```
startDate <-  as.Date("2019-01-01")
endDate <- as.Date("2019-01-07")
numDays <- endDate - startDate + 1
newData <- data.frame(Date=seq(startDate, endDate, 1),
                      UVI=sample(1:10, numDays, rep=TRUE))
for(i in 1:length(SMALen)) {
    newData <- cbind(newData, NA)
    colName <- paste0("SMA", SMALen[i])
    names(newData)[ncol(newData)] = colName
}
numRows <- nrow(myData)
myData <- rbind(myData, newData)
tail(myData, 25)
```

And this is the code I want to replace with roll_mean or similar:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(newData)) {
    for(j in 1:length(SMALen)) {
        colName <- paste0("SMA", SMALen[j])
        endDate <- newData$Date[i]
        startDate <- endDate - SMALen[j] + 1
        SMA <- mean(myData$UVI[(myData$Date >= startDate) & (myData$Date <= endDate)])
        myData[numRows + i, j + 2] <- SMA

    }    
}
tail(myData, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to take last (maximum window size) 165 rows from old data (only Date and UVI) and add the new data (Date and UVI) using rbind and then apply roll_mean to the new data frame with loop as you did in your first loop. Once done with adding SMA values, add back the data frame with your old data with SMA values.